# Bcachefs remove device without mounting, or mount with device offline

Tags: linux, mount, btrfs

Using bcachefs (Arch Linux 6.7.2), how can I remove a non-existent device without the device being present?

The X-problem is:

1. I've added a test drive to my daily drive using `bcachefs device add`
2. I never wrote anything to it after adding the drive.
3. I forgot to remove the test drive, unplugged it and formatted it for something else. The bcachefs headers on the test drive no longer exist.
4. Now I rebooted my system, and my daily drive cannot mount.

Using either `mount` or `bcachefs mount` would result in the following:

[image: mount error]

The following would show in `dmesg`:

```
bcachefs: bch2_fs_open() bch_fs_open err opening /dev/sda: insufficient_devices_to_start
```

I tried using the `degraded` and `very_degraded` options. I was able to mount the drive using `mount -o very_degraded`, but I cannot remove the device:

```
> sudo dmesg
...
bcachefs (18d26ec7-ad0d-460f-a35f-1a9533bccaf0): mounting version 1.3: rebalance_work opts=very_degraded
bcachefs (18d26ec7-ad0d-460f-a35f-1a9533bccaf0): recovering from clean shutdown, journal seq 379785
bcachefs (18d26ec7-ad0d-460f-a35f-1a9533bccaf0): alloc_read... done
bcachefs (18d26ec7-ad0d-460f-a35f-1a9533bccaf0): stripes_read... done
bcachefs (18d26ec7-ad0d-460f-a35f-1a9533bccaf0): snapshots_read... done
bcachefs (18d26ec7-ad0d-460f-a35f-1a9533bccaf0): journal_replay... done
bcachefs (18d26ec7-ad0d-460f-a35f-1a9533bccaf0): resume_logged_ops... done
bcachefs (18d26ec7-ad0d-460f-a35f-1a9533bccaf0): going read-write

> sudo bcachefs device remove 02d58ad4-29c5-4dcb-b7d6-d4c718590b33 /data   
stat error statting 02d58ad4-29c5-4dcb-b7d6-d4c718590b33: No such file or directory

> sudo bcachefs device remove 1 /data
BCH_IOCTL_DISK_REMOVE ioctl error: Invalid argument
bcachefs (dev-1): Cannot remove without losing data
```

[image]

Comment: Why the `btrfs` tag?